# Rails internationalization if check not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, internationalization

I have a rails app and working with two languages.

Interestingly, when I check the following in `main.html.erb`;

```
MYLOCAL <%= I18n.locale == "en" %>|<%= I18n.locale %>
```

outputs;

```
false|en
```

Why would that happen ?

Comment: What are trying to achieve? It shows exactly what you've written in your code.

Comment: did you actually get your answer? I thought you mistyped `==` instead of `=` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `I18n.locale` returns a symbol. In your case `:en`.

And `<%= I18n.locale %>` calls `to_s`

For correct result try:

```
<%= I18n.locale.to_s == "en" %>|<%= I18n.locale %>
```

or

```
<%= I18n.locale == :en %>|<%= I18n.locale %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I18n.locale
#return :en which is a symbol

I18n.locale == :en #return true
```

Note: Comparing `Symbol` would be a better practice than converting it to a `String` and comparing it.